# How to test an ES6 generator function from an ES5 test framework

Tags: ecmascript-6, traceur

Given an ES6 class with generator function how do you run that generator function from ES5 code:

```
class GeneratorClass {

    constructor() {
        this.ary = [1, 2, 3];
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let el of this.ary) {
            yield el;
        }
    }

}

// This runs fine transcompiled (traceur)
var iterableObj = new GeneratorClass();
for (let el of iterableObj) {
    console.log(el);
}
```

From an ES5 testing framework:

```
TestCase('GeneratorClassTest', {
    setUp: function () {
        console.log('in setup');
        var iterableObj = new GeneratorClass();
        for (var el in this.iterableObj) {
            console.log(el);
        }
    },

    testConstructor: function() {

    }  
});
```

This does not throw any errors, will run the setup function, however does not iterate through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just requiring your ES6 module from runtime which only supports ES5, you can't do this.

But if you're compiling your ES6 module into ES5 using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) and then requiring your compiled module - you can test your generator in ES5 runtime. Just not use `for of` loop, create `iteratorObj` using `Symbol.iterator` method, and the use `when` loop and [`next`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) method of iterator.

For your example:

```
TestCase('GeneratorClassTest', {
    setUp: function () {
        console.log('in setup');
        var generator = new GeneratorClass();
        var next, iterableObj = generator[Symbol.iterator]();

        while ((next = iterableObj.next()) && !next.done) {
            console.log(next.value);
        }
    },

    testConstructor: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: I've put this through both the original project and a second scratchpad project + debugger - `iterableObj` does not appear to have a `.next()` property (anywhere in its prototype chain) for some odd reason (using `traceur` to trans compile the ES6).

Comment: @user5321531 Sorry,  I made a mistake. Now it must work. Try it

Comment: Oo, operator precedence. Of course it must be `(next = iterableObj.next()) && !next.done`. I fixed it.